How to replace a char within a string in VSCode find/replace?
Using VSCode find/replace, how would I find all strings within a file conforming to the following, and replace all dashes in some-text-that-looks-like-this with underscores?
text: some-text-that-looks-like-this 
{text: some-text-that-looks-like-this}
text: some-text-that-looks-like-this, some other text....

All strings of "some-text-that-looks-like-this" start with "some-text".
I do some regex and I can find all instances of some-text-that-looks-like-this, i.e.
(some-text-.*)\b

But have no clue how to replace '-' with '_' at running time.

Is the text:  at the start of the lines actually part of your text?


I do some regex and i can find all instances of some-text-that-looks-like-this, i.e.
(some-text-.*)\b


After that, do CtrlShiftP -> Select All Occurences of Find Match to select all matching words.
Then click Find in Selection button (the button with three horizontal lines in the "find" popup).
Then just type - in "find" and _ in "replace", and click Replace All.

If the text:  is actually in the text you are searching (and not just in your question to illustrate the issue) you can do this with a single regex:
Find: (?<=text: some-text[-\w]*)-|(?<=text: )(some)-(text)
Replace: $1_$2
See regex101 demo
This will work in vscode's Find Widget (within the current file), but not in the Search view (across multiple files) due to the non-fixed length lookbehind.
When the first part of the regex matches ((?<=text: some-text[-\w]*)-) there is no capture group 1 or 2 so the replace $1_$2 will only replace the matched -'s.
When the second part of the regex ((?<=text: )(some)-(text)) matches then $1 = some and $2 = text .
